# How to save formulas defined by end users in the table field (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, plsql

**Hi,
I need to store formulas in a table field, the formula will have a variable called salario. The idea is evaluate the formula  through a code block to get a result.**

Example:

```
TABLE NAME: CONCEPTO

Field CONCEPTO: VARCHAR

Field FORMULA: VARCHAR

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
CONCEPTO  -    FORMULA
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
 AFP ----- (salario * 0.0625)
 ISSS -----(salario * 0.030)
 RENTA-----(salario * 0.100)
```

**Now through a stored procedure or function I pretend execute to evaluate the formula and change the variable salario by the variable sueldo.
In this way i want to get a result**

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_calculo AS

  CURSOR cur_concepto_empleado IS
    SELECT concepto, formula
      FROM concepto;

  formula   VARCHAR2(50);
  descuento NUMBER;
  sueldo    NUMBER;

  BEGIN

    FOR reg_conemp IN cur_concepto_empleado
    LOOP

      sueldo := 400;

      formula := replace(reg_conemp.formula, "salario", sueldo);

      -- THIS IS THE LINE 38:
      descuento := to_number(formula, "99");

      dbms_output.put_line(descuento);

    END LOOP;
END PR_CALCULO;
```

**The result obtained is:**

```
Conectando a la base de datos DBwwww.
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: error numérico o de valor
ORA-06512: en "RRHH.PR_CALCULO", línea 38
ORA-06512: en línea 2
El proceso ha terminado.
Desconectando de la base de datos DBwwww.
```

**How I can resolve this case?
What would you recommend me?
I need to store formulas in table fields for after execute a process (Code) that evaluate the formulas to get a result....**

**Thanks...**

Comment: Please translate error to english.

Answer (score 1):

You are not multiplying the values ,because it is string,so i dynamically multiply the numbers.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PR_CALCULO AS

cursor cur_concepto_empleado is
 select concepto, formula from concepto;

formula varchar2(50);
descuento number;
sueldo number;

begin

for reg_conemp in cur_concepto_empleado
loop

  sueldo := 400;

  formula := replace(reg_conemp.formula,'salario',sueldo);

  execute immediate 'select '||formula ||'   from dual' into descuento;
  --the values dint get multiplied because you store that as string
  --and the string contains * ,so to_number will not work
  --descuento := to_number(formula,'99'); --THIS IS THE LINE 38

  dbms_output.put_line(descuento);

 end loop;

END PR_CALCULO;​​
/
```

Answer (score 1):

First a general remark about Oracle languages you have to use simple quotes **'** and not double quotes **"** most of the times (except for column titles and some xml functions).

For your question, you're near to the answer by yourself. Here you have to use the **execute immediate** command. This command is used to execute dynamically generated code.

```
PROCEDURE PR_CALCULO AS

formula   VARCHAR2(32767);
descuento NUMBER;
sueldo    number := 400;

BEGIN
formula := 'begin :result := ' || REPLACE('(salario * 0.0625)', 'salario', sueldo) || '; end;';
dbms_output.put_line(formula);

execute immediate formula using out descuento; --THIS IS THE LINE 38

dbms_output.put_line(descuento);

END PR_CALCULO;
```

In the formula definition you can see ':result' variable you don't have to declare it. It's local to dynamic code.
Then executing your formula you bind the "dynamic variables" to "real variables" with **using** statement. Your result is obviously an out variable for the dynamic code.

And finally if you add ':' before your variables in your stored formula you can shorten your code to

```
PROCEDURE PR_CALCULO2 AS

formula   VARCHAR2(32767);
descuento NUMBER;
sueldo    number := 400;

BEGIN
formula := 'begin :result := (:salario * 0.0625); end;';

execute immediate formula using out descuento, in sueldo; --THIS IS THE LINE 38

dbms_output.put_line(descuento);

END PR_CALCULO2;
```

The **dynamic variables** are binded to **real variables** in order from left to right.
**:result** is the first **dynamic variable** so it's binded to the first **real variable** which is an out variable.
**:salario** which is the second one is binded to the second variable **sueldo** which is an in variable.
**in**, **out** and **in out** are from dynamic code point of view.

Hope this helps

Regards

Comment: As Eric mentioned here, modify the table data from `(salario * 0.0625)` to `(:salario * 0.0625)` and so on for each row and then use dynamic SQL as suggested.

Comment: I have replicated the code that you gave me.
It worked perfectly.....

thank very much for help me.

Comment: I used the second example, I stored the character ":" with the formula in the field of the table, and It worked perfectly.....